# Can't boot into xorg after update!

Tags: graphics, xorg, amd-graphics

After yesterdays updates I just end up with a black screen after booting.
I have an AMD/ATI Mars Radeon HD 8730M gfx card.

I've tried re-installing xserver like this, http://helewix.com/howto/ubuntu-17-10-black-screen-solution/

I've also tried the disk in another computer but it's the same.

The error I'm seeing in Xorg.0.log is:
open /dev/fb0: Permission denied

If this is not a general issue with Ubuntu the only thing I can think of is that I might have tried to install a proprietary driver a while back as I was desperate to get a docking station to work with video for my second monitor. It didn't work anyway though.

`$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 0b)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 0b)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB xHCI HC (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series HECI #0 (rev 04)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I218-LM (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev e4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev e4)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev e4)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev e4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series SMBus Controller (rev 04)
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev 73)
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Mars [Radeon HD 8730M] (rev ff)
03:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cape Verde/Pitcairn HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 7700/7800 Series] (rev ff)
04:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5227 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)`

Comment: See the logfile Xorg.0.log, https://www.dropbox.com/s/5p7ww3fgzuk4r7b/Xorg.0.log?dl=0

Comment: When I re-installed Ubuntu 18.04 on a new disk I have slightly older versions of xorg-server and linux kernel. Why could that be? Can I downgrade on the faulty disk? How would I do that? See Xorg log from the new install here and compare to the above, https://www.dropbox.com/s/uu6keif467i2wn8/Xorg.1.log-1804?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this is not a driver problem. This is due to a change in the X server, which has been switched from root to rootless. This is a very common problem. Since the X server is now rootless, it doesn't have permission to access the frame buffer device. Actually, it should auto-detect, when root is needed. But often it doesn't. There are 2 settings for that. You might want to read man Xwrapper.config to learn about it. However, this usually doesn't really solve the problem. You also need to add the user(s) to the video group (sudo usermod -a -G video LOGINNAME). If you still get and error, you might need to set your environment variable DISPLAY too. This is either done by something like export DISPLAY=127.0.0.1:2.0 (temporary) or in /etc/environment (permanent).

Comment: I tried those three things but it didn't change anything and the error is still there. I'm not sure the error is fatal though? Maybe it's something else that causes xorg not to start? Thanks!

Comment: This actually works in regards to the framebuffer permission error you stated in the question. However, in regards to your own answer I can agree. At this point it becomes a mixed problem and one could cause the other. If the driver is not working or the right one, it doesn't work either. I too had problems with the NVidia driver after an upgrade, breaking the whole GUI system.

Comment: OK, thanks. I still have the error in the log but the system works despite that.

Answer (score 0):

OK this is now fixed and I'm much happier!! =)

I purged the ppa ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers which contained proprietary drivers for amd radeon gfx cards. See instructions when adding the ppa how to purge it.

Then it worked like normal again! Using proprietary drivers and then updating the system is asking for trouble.. One day to waste. I hope somebody else will learn from my mistake.

Info on how to install/uninstall the amd radeon drivers:
https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-latest-amd-radeon-drivers-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux